# How am I meant to add an apostrophe into this piece of code

Tags: python

So I have created this piece of code...

```
name = input("What is your name?")
print ("This is", name,"'s first program")
```

but it shows up like this

```
This is John 's first program
```

however I don't want there to be a space between John and the apostrophe. What should I do.

Comment: `print("This is {}'s first program".format(name))`? Just passing multiple arguments to `print` will always put a space between them unless you set `sep=''`, in which case you also need to add back in the space after `is`.

Comment: Thank you for the code, it works! - can you explain to me what the curly brackets and the .format name do

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3/library/string.html#formatstrings